# How can i deploy full stack app to the firebase which is build on React Node and using mysql database

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs, firebase-hosting

I have build an app full stack app using the React Node and Mysql database,I want to deploy to the firebase instead of heroku, previously my apps are deployed on the heroku.First i am using the firebase how can I deploy to firebase?

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/quickstart

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Hosting only supports serving static resources, like HTML and client-side JavaScript, and (through Cloud Functions or Cloud Run) short-lived HTTPS requests. It cannot be used to host a MySQL database.